# "It can be seen as"

Tags: phrase-request, synonyms

I would like to have a synonym of (**It can be seen as**). I understand the meaning of this sentence but would like to use a synonym without changing the meaning.

**Example**

**This estimation equation can be seen as a Bayesian rule.**

Comment: The question is broad; get us an example to answer it.

Comment: While some synonym(s) may exist, there are situations where I would not replace it for anything in the world - as it is the best choice. As @Maulik said, please provide example(s).

Comment: @MaulikV Thank you for your comment. I have added an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you continue in the same style:

> This estimation equation **can be seen as** a Bayesian rule.
>   This equation
>   can be **taken** as a Bayesian rule.
>   This equation can be **chosen**
>   as Bayesian rule.

Maybe wrong.

Comment: I think the last one is indeed a poor choice. Perhaps _interpreted_ would be better than _chosen_. Using _taken_, though, would work.